# How do you fix an almost-correct characteristic equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose I have a differential equation $$y'(t)=ay(t)+b.$$

If I "plug in" $y(t)=e^{ \lambda t}$ as a test solution, I would arrive at the characteristic equation $$ \lambda e^{\lambda t} = ae^{ \lambda t} + b.$$ If I didn't have that extra $b$ term, I could easily divide out the $e^{ \lambda t}$ and have no problems solving for $\lambda$.

However, given that you can "almost" solve for $ \lambda$ and that the actual solution itself isn't very different, $y(t) = y_0e^{at}-\frac{b}{a}$, it implies there must have been some predictable way to "fix" the original guess. Is there a general method of using a of combination of algebra and calculus to make substitutions or differentiate\integrate a characteristic equation until it becomes solvable for $\lambda$? And then after you have completed all those steps, what then does it imply about your original solution?

Answer (score 1):

Considering instead $z = y+c_0$ we have

$$
(y+c_0)' = a(y+c_0)+b\Rightarrow y'=a y +a c_0 + b
$$

so choosing $c_0 = -\frac ba$ we have now

$$
z'=a z
$$

without additional constant.

NOTE

For linear DE's we can make $y = y_h + y_p$ such that

$$
\cases{
y_h'+a y_h = 0\\
y_p'+a y_p = b
}
$$

The determination of $y_p$ is considering any $y_p$ which obeys it's DE. For instance, if $b = c_0+c_1 x$ we can determine $y_p$ by considering $y_p = b_1 x + b_0$ so after substitution we have

$$
(b_1 x+b_0)' = a(b_1 x+ b_0) + c_0+c_1 x\Rightarrow\cases{b_1=a b_0+c_0\\ a b_1 - c_1 = 0}
$$

and then, after $y_p$ determination we have

$$
(y_h+y_p)' + a (y_h+y_p) = 0
$$

Comment: But how do you know to consider $z=y+c_0$? What was your goal? Surely this won't work for other situations. Is $z$ a function of $t$? A function of $y$? Can you be more explicit?

Comment: @MoreQuestions3 Please. See attached note.

Comment: I'm not seeing a note attached anywhere. Do you mean just added text to the answer?